# Definition of TraditionalForm

Tags: boxes, traditional-form, open-source, introspection

This is a followup of ["How to check for Mathematica’s definition of XY?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156/39260), a question by uli on how to access the definition of a built-in symbol.  That question focused on `Binomial` but mentioned that it could be good to read the source for `TraditionalForm` or `TeXForm` in order to tweak it or build on top of it.

So my question is, how can I find the transformation rules involved in making a `TraditionalForm`?  Removing its attribute `ReadProtected` is not enough to see the actual transformations as the code seems to be hidden in some further indirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Information[TraditionalForm]` indicates that `TraditionalForm` is `ReadProtected` (and `Protected`).  We can remove that with `ClearAttributes[TraditionalForm, {Protected, ReadProtected}]`.

Then `Information[TraditionalForm]` shows only a few definitions: besides some for dots and for `InactiveDTraditional`, there are definitions for use within `MakeExpression` or `MakeBoxes`,

```
MakeBoxes[BoxForm`apat$_,TraditionalForm]^:=BoxForm`BoxFormAutoLoad[
  MakeBoxes,
  BoxForm`apat$,
  TraditionalForm,
  "Typeset`TraditionalForm`",
  {{TraditionalForm,MakeBoxes},{TraditionalForm,MakeExpression}}]

MakeExpression[BoxForm`apat$_,TraditionalForm]^:=BoxForm`BoxFormAutoLoad[
  MakeExpression,
  BoxForm`apat$,
  TraditionalForm,
  "Typeset`TraditionalForm`",
  {{TraditionalForm,MakeBoxes},{TraditionalForm,MakeExpression}}]
```

Digging a bit, `` BoxForm`BoxFormAutoLoad `` loads the file 
`` System`Private`$SystemFileDir<>System`Dump`fixfile[#4]<>"x" `` then the definition that called `` BoxForm`BoxFormAutoLoad `` is `UnSet` to avoid loading the file twice.  In our case, `#4` is `` "Typeset`TraditionalForm`" ``, leading on my system to loading the `.mx` file

```
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\Typeset\TraditionalForm.mx
```

Files with the extension `.mx` are binary files that contain definitions of some symbols and can be read with `Get`.  Unfortunately, `Trace[Get[filename]]` does not show what is going on when *Mathematica* reads the file.  More elaborate tricks redefining `Set` or `SetDelayed` using code from ["Overriding a built-in function with custom coded procedures"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95720/39260) do not help.  As far as I can tell, when reading an `.mx` file, *Mathematica* directly injects the stored definitions without invoking `Set` or `SetDelayed`.  So we cannot see rules as they are added.

After failing in that direction (and staring for an hour at the irrelevant `Trace[Import[filename]]`), I realized we can simply look at `Information[TraditionalForm]` again.  It now gives a rather lengthy output: 64 `FormatValues`.  For instance, a simple rule

```
HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[Function[x_, y_], TraditionalForm]] :>
  RowBox[{Parenthesize[x, TraditionalForm, Set, Left],
    "\[Function]",
    Parenthesize[y, TraditionalForm, Set, Right]}]
```

defining how a function f:x->y should be converted to boxes.  (There are rules with `MakeExpression` which do the opposite transformation from boxes to an expression.)  However, this is not the end, as there are still some rules which call `` BoxForm`BoxFormAutoLoad ``.  For such rules, *Mathematica* loads yet another `.mx` file and the only way to know its contents is to load it and take another look at `FormatValues[TraditionalForm]`.

Depending on our aim, it can be worth loading all files

```
Get /@ FileNames["*.mx", 
   DirectoryName[
    System`Private`$SystemFileDir <> 
     System`Dump`fixfile["Typeset`TraditionalForm`"] <> "x"]];
```

However, this does not run the code in `` BoxForm`BoxFormAutoLoad `` that removes definitions involving it.  One way that seems to work is to `TagUnset` the `FormatValues` that involve `` BoxForm`BoxFormAutoLoad ``, but I wouldn't trust that in production code.

```
Unprotect[TraditionalForm];
Scan[(If[Not[FreeQ[Hold[#[[2]]], BoxForm`BoxFormAutoLoad]],
     TagUnset[TraditionalForm, 
      Evaluate[(#[[1]] /. Verbatim[HoldPattern][x_] :> Hold[x] /. 
          Verbatim[HoldPattern][y_] :> y /. Hold :> HoldPattern)]]]) &,
  FormatValues[TraditionalForm]];
```

Sorry for the ugly code as the second argument of `TagUnset`: there, `#[[1]]` is the left-hand side of a rule, but it takes the form `HoldPattern[somename:HoldPattern[somepattern___]]` and I had to remove the inner `HoldPattern`.

Comment: Perhaps you will benefit from the function `PrintDefinitions` from the package ``GeneralUtilities` ``. That is, `PrintDefinitions@TraditionalForm`